# Laravel impersonate user without using a package

Tags: laravel, impersonation

I would like to know how to impersonate user without using a package in Laravel/Vue application. I'm using Passport for authentification.
From my understanding and how I think it might work is that I test if the master password is entered and then the admin user is automatically redirected to the user account which is taken from the email which is also entered but I cannot understand how exactly this should be done. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I implemented impersonation with Sanctum a while back. Made a blog post about it. Maybe that can set you in the right direction? https://jymden.com/impersonate-user-with-sanctum-in-laravel/

Comment: How do you implement user protection in your application? If you are using Policies, then you could just allow admins to use the desired actions.